# Reading EXIF/MetaData from CRW (or other RAW files) with PHP

Tags: php, metadata, jpeg, tiff, exif

Pretty much as the title says, I've had a search around but been unable to find anything. I can read TIFF and JPEG files, but I've not found anything to read RAW files. Does anyone know of anything PHP or otherwise that can do this (if otherwise, then something I can use with PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience is this field , but I found a perl tool that I think will do the trick:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/